# Base theme for magento

Tags: theme, magento2.4, base

Is it is possible to create base theme, which will become a common theme to both the adminhtml and frontend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say this is not feasible since you have the **registration.php** where you are declaring your theme component by initially mentioning the **area** it is dedicated to.

For backend you have:

```php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'adminhtml/%vendor_dir/your_theme_dir%', __DIR__);
```

For frontend you have:

```php
use \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::THEME, 'frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>', __DIR__);
```

So basically, you can't have the same theme as a single component declared on 2 areas in the same time due to the *registration.php* file instructions.

---

***Some sidenotes:***

Let's take the example of the ***backend (adminhtml)*** - assuming you don't want to write everything from scratch, you will have to rely on the Magento default backend theme and your custom theme will have to mention the inheritance in the `theme.xml` file with the `<parent>Magento/backend</parent>` property. If you want to also start from Magento_Blank or Luma for frontend, you will have to inherit one of them also, so again, you won't be able to inherit 2 themes in the same time due to the tehme inheritance mechanism in Magento.

In addition, in the **admin -> Content -> Design -> Themes** you get a filtered list of the **frontend** themes only. A list that is retrieved by a resource model specifically filters the list of themes assigned to the frontend area based on the *registration.php* file. Once again, you can't assign both frontend and backend here.